# Returning a string when the return type is an object in a REST service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, intellij-idea

I am creating a REST Service which returns user objects that can be filtered. I use @ResponseBody User when I return a user. But when the id doesn't exist, I want to display a String saying "Please provide a valid user ID". How do I do this when the return type is User?

code:

```
@GetMapping("/{Id}")
    public @ResponseBody User getUserPath(@PathVariable int Id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(Id).get();
        if (user==null){
            //return "Please provide a valid user ID"
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: You should return a 404 in that case. With that message if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will do your job. This will return your custom string and the correct HTTP status code as well.

```
@GetMapping("/{Id}")
public ResponseEntity<User>  getUserPath(@RequestParam int Id) {

    User user = userRepository.findById(Id).get();
    if (user==null){
        return new ResponseEntity("Please provide a valid user ID", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.FOUND);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply return object
`public @ResponseBody Object getUserPath()`

**update 1**:
IMHO much better in this case is to throw exception, handle it with `@ControllerAdvice` + `@ExceptionHandler` and return error with string there